# Remove JTable Column identifier

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

I wan' t to customize the apparence of my `JTable`. I wan' t to remove the column identifiers that's hold the column name. I don' t want to simply leave it blank but I wan't to "hide" that. any suggestion? thanks!

Comment: *"remove the column identifiers that's hold the column name."* Why did you put them there in the first place?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson most likely by using a `JScrollPane` to contain the table, which adds those automagically.

Comment: @Robin  Interested in facts rather than speculation, on this one.  ..Mostly I just want to play with the code, but that 1st thing sounded more 'professional', no?

Comment: I think that is best to hide the column identifiers because in this case I can keep all the table advantage. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide the table header this way:

```
table.getTableHeader().setVisible(false);
```

Or you can remove it entirely:

```
table.setTableHeader(null);
```

Comment: works great! Thanks! Why I can' t mark your answer as correct?